# Different Debian versions from two different commands

Tags: debian, kernel, version

I wanted to check my current Debian version so I typed  `uname -a` and it gave me some stuff including `Debian 3.2.73`.

But Then I found this command `cat /etc/debian_version` and it gave me `Debian 7.9`

1- What is the difference between the two commands & 2-Which version is installed?

Comment: The first is the version of your kernel, the second the Debian release number...

Comment: @jasonwryan Thanks, you may make this as answer to be marked :)

Comment: @jasonwryan So my release is Wheezy?

Comment: I recommend using `lsb_release -a` for printing distribution specific information

Comment: @Pandya, `3.2.0-4-amd64`

Comment: @Pandya, Yes `lsb_release -a` is the best. Thansk, man :)

Comment: post the full output of `uname -a` in your question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### uname

It prints the name, version and other details about the current machine and the operating system *kernel* running on it.

3.2.73 is *kernel version* of your operating system. When you run the command shows the updated Operating system, kernel version, released date etc.

### /etc/debian_version

This command is used to Check version you of the *Debian distribution* you are running.